# how can remove "right shift" shortcut its not include on keyboard shortcut

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

After updating Ubuntu, the button has changed Change the language,
I went to settings then Change the options on the keyboard ,It was not included in the list
What's the solution?

[image]

how can remove "right shift" shortcut its not include on keyboard shortcut

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### Below is an excerpt from this page https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-language.html.en hopefully this helps.

Open the Activities overview and start typing Region & Language.

Click on Region & Language to open the panel.

Click Language.

Select your desired region and language. If your region and language are not listed, click … at the bottom of the list to select from all available regions and languages.

Click Select to save.

Your session needs to be restarted for changes to take effect. Either click Restart…, or manually log back in later.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).